# Customize asp.net-identity objects and tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have been following this guide to get started with an MVC application.  However I was not able to find any answers to my questions online or figure it out on my own how to make few modifications.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

I wish to change the name of the default tables in the database that get created with "out of the box" login system.  How would I overwrite the model to do that?  Needless to say I wish for things to continue working.

I also wish to add more properties to the account table, I am assuming that the answer would tie in with my previous question.

Any links to guides or points in right direction would be most appreciated.  I spent most of the week trying to figure this out with no luck.

For the record I have followed the guide there to the letter and I have everything working, I am able to register with email or with google.  But I am having a lot of troubles understanding how to make changes to libraries I have no access to in MVC5.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you need this: [Customize MVC 5 Users](http://blog.falafel.com/customize-mvc-5-application-users-using-asp-net-identity-2-0/)

The trick is to find where the models for identity are defined and change them.
(i.e. the DBContext)

After you change them, you can either delete all your existing db stuff so that it can be recreated OR run migration scripts.

Finally, anything you chaged or added will have to be reflected in the Controllers / Views. (i.e. If you added a new field, then you need a new textbox to capture that field.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer hatcyl, I'm only confused about finding where the models for identity are defined, how do I find them, what am I looking for?